# Golang's zlib is not compressing

Tags: go, compression, zlib

I have the following piece of code that takes a hex string and converts it into byte array; But when I try to compress the mentioned byte array using zlib it doesn't work(I print the data before and after compression but there are the same):

```
        data, err := hex.DecodeString(request.Log)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(data)
        var writer bytes.Buffer
        gz := zlib.NewWriter(&writer)
        if _, err = gz.Write(data); err != nil {
            println("error: ", err)
            return
        }

        gz.Flush()
        if err = gz.Close(); err != nil {
            println("err", err)
            return
        }

        fmt.Println(data)
```

I also tried to manually flush the writer before closing it but it didn't help.

Comment: The compressed data is written to the `writer` buffer. The original `data` slice is not modified, and you print it before and after. Why would it change? Print `writer.Bytes()`.

Comment: @icza Oh right I see...that was a silly mistake ,I mistook `gz` for writer at first and the rest was a downward spiral of confusion and errors XD ...thank you for your help...If you want you can add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it since you answered sooner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are printing the wrong variable in last line. It should be `fmt.Println(writer.Bytes())`